# problem with pandas efficiency when working with dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of code that runs but that is not scaling well with bigger dataset AT ALL. We are talking about minutes with big datasets. 
Here is a toy dataset to illustrate the issue:

```
         Id Supplier  Avg_NetAmountSpent            Date  Quantity  NetAmount
0    185781    SAXON         2953.500000      2020-05-10       401       9294
1    185781    SAXON         2953.500000      2020-05-09      3502       8890
2    185781    SAXON         2953.500000      2020-05-08      7380       8381
3    185781    SAXON         2953.500000      2020-05-08      3384       1734
4    185781    SAXON         2953.500000      2020-05-08      4826       4910
612  467809    SAXONIS         861.666667      2020-05-09       314       1854
613  467809    SAXONIS         861.666667      2020-05-08      3347        727
614  467809    SAXONIS         861.666667      2020-05-08      4875       6744
615  467809    SAXONIS         861.666667      2020-05-10      3000       2754
616  467809    SAXONIS         861.666667      2020-05-10      7807       8763
```

And my code looks like this. The issue is coming from the last line.

```
today1 = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
frequency1 = '1D'
Nbin1 = (today1 - data_initial['Date'].min()) // pd.Timedelta(frequency1) + 1# Number of bins
bins1 = [today1 - n * pd.Timedelta(frequency1) for n in range(Nbin1, -1, -1)]

data11 = data_initial.groupby(['Id', pd.cut(data_initial['Date'], bins=bins1)]).sum().reset_index()
```

the output of the code of the following:

```
        Id                      Date  Quantity  NetAmount  
0   185781  (2020-05-07, 2020-05-08]  244780.0   372349.0        
1   185781  (2020-05-08, 2020-05-09]  208825.0   364153.0        
2   185781  (2020-05-09, 2020-05-10]  214401.0   314165.0      
3   185781  (2020-05-10, 2020-05-11]  NaN        NaN               
4   332146  (2020-05-07, 2020-05-08]  261302.0   450012.0   
5   332146  (2020-05-08, 2020-05-09]  268464.0   498076.0   
6   332146  (2020-05-09, 2020-05-10]  279866.0   432608.0    
7   332146  (2020-05-10, 2020-05-11]  NaN        NaN    
8   467809  (2020-05-07, 2020-05-08]  337624.0   568162.0
9   467809  (2020-05-08, 2020-05-09]  327044.0   496085.0 
10  467809  (2020-05-09, 2020-05-10]  275298.0   383322.0 
11  467809  (2020-05-10, 2020-05-11]  NaN        NaN
```

UPDATE: Some modifications made the code much faster to execute:

```
frequency1 = '1D'

data_initial['Period from Today'] = abs((pd.to_datetime(data_initial['Date'])-today1).dt.days)

data1 = data_initial.groupby(['Id', 'Date','Period from Today' ]).agg({'Quantity' : sum, 'NetAmount': sum}).reset_index()
```

resulting in the following output:

```
       Id       Date  Period from Today  Quantity  NetAmount
0  285556 2020-05-06                  5    218716     369230
1  285556 2020-05-07                  4    345800     441942
2  285556 2020-05-08                  3    226062     339148
3  443756 2020-05-06                  5    782724    1187067
4  443756 2020-05-07                  4    839970    1234092
5  443756 2020-05-08                  3    929337    1049235
```

but it needs to look like that

```
       Id       Date  Period from Today  Quantity  NetAmount
0  285556 2020-05-06                  5    218716     369230
1  285556 2020-05-07                  4    345800     441942
2  285556 2020-05-08                  3    226062     339148
2  285556 2020-05-09                  2    0               0
2  285556 2020-05-10                  1    0               0
2  285556 2020-05-11                  0    0               0 

etc...
```

However there is still an issue there. How could I tweak what I to get it so the dates go up to the current date, rather than the most recent date in the dataset?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I am not sure what exacly you want to get. why are you using bins? if you want to groupby id and resample by day, so you get the summed values by day for each id. you should use [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html)

Comment: because it needs to start off from the current's day and not from the dataset most recent date, I am not sure that resampling allows to do that