# pandas dataframe: resample to include all the dates from today's date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am really struggling with something that sounded trivial when I first looked into it. I have asked a similar question here [problem with pandas efficiency when working with dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726593/problem-with-pandas-efficiency-when-working-with-dates?noredirect=1#comment109184533_61726593)
 where I was more wondering about the efficiency about one piece of code. I figure I could make a new post as I think that finding out a way to modify a dataframe as such could be helpful to more people than just me.

I need to modify a dataframe to include in it, all the days from the current date.

example:

```
       Id     Supplier  Avg_NetAmountSpent        Date  Quantity  NetAmount
0  206433     BESNOWED              6593.0  2020-05-08        91      10181
1  206433     BESNOWED              6593.0  2020-05-06      1076       6069
2  206434  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0  2020-05-08        91      10181
3  206434  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0  2020-05-06      1076       6069
```

and I'd like to be change the dataframe so it looks like that:

```
       Id     Supplier  Avg_NetAmountSpent        Date  Quantity  NetAmount
0  206433     BESNOWED              6593.0  2020-05-06        91      10181
1  206433     BESNOWED                   0  2020-05-07         0          0
2  206433     BESNOWED              6593.0  2020-05-08        91      10181
3  206433     BESNOWED                   0  2020-05-09         0          0
4  206433     BESNOWED                   0  2020-05-10         0          0
5  206433     BESNOWED                   0  2020-05-11         0          0
6  206434  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0  2020-05-06      1076       6069
7  206434  LENTIVECTOR                   0  2020-05-07         0          0
8  206434  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0  2020-05-08        91      10181
9  206434  LENTIVECTOR                   0  2020-05-09         0          0
10  206434  LENTIVECTOR                  0  2020-05-10         0          0
11  206434  LENTIVECTOR                  0  2020-05-11         0          0
```

I have tryed doing this but this is so unefficient and it would be easier to have it in the format above:

```
today1 = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()
frequency1 = '1D'
Nbin1 = (today1 - data_initial['Date'].min()) // pd.Timedelta(frequency1) + 1# Number of bins
bins1 = [today1 - n * pd.Timedelta(frequency1) for n in range(Nbin1, -1, -1)]

data11 = data_initial.groupby(['Id', pd.cut(data_initial['Date'], bins=bins1)]).sum().reset_index()
```

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: you asked the same question 3h ago. voting for close

Comment: i reformulated to be better explained my issue as I am working on it. I don't think that  your comment was any helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
new_df = data_initial.set_index('Date').groupby('Id').apply(
    lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(data_initial['Date'].min(), 'today', freq='1D'), fill_value=np.nan)
).drop('Id', axis=1).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Date'})
new_df.loc[:,'Supplier'] = new_df.loc[:,'Supplier'].ffill()
new_df = new_df.fillna(0)
new_df

        Id       Date     Supplier  Avg_NetAmountSpent  Quantity  NetAmount
0   206433 2020-05-06     BESNOWED              6593.0    1076.0     6069.0
1   206433 2020-05-07     BESNOWED                 0.0       0.0        0.0
2   206433 2020-05-08     BESNOWED              6593.0      91.0    10181.0
3   206433 2020-05-09     BESNOWED                 0.0       0.0        0.0
4   206433 2020-05-10     BESNOWED                 0.0       0.0        0.0
5   206433 2020-05-11     BESNOWED                 0.0       0.0        0.0
6   206434 2020-05-06  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0    1076.0     6069.0
7   206434 2020-05-07  LENTIVECTOR                 0.0       0.0        0.0
8   206434 2020-05-08  LENTIVECTOR              7335.0      91.0    10181.0
9   206434 2020-05-09  LENTIVECTOR                 0.0       0.0        0.0
10  206434 2020-05-10  LENTIVECTOR                 0.0       0.0        0.0
11  206434 2020-05-11  LENTIVECTOR                 0.0       0.0        0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see how you are trying to do it. That's clever. Right now it gives the error "cannot re-index from a duplicate axis". Not sure why yet